# VueJS failed to compile: dependency not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I have this file I am referencing in my VueJS project, that seems to cause a compilation error. The dependency is declared not found at the location, even though I can perfectly find it in my node_modules directories...

On the left of the picture are my directories, where you can see the desired file. At the bottom of the screen is my terminal, displaying the error. At the top of the screen is my import statement of the desired file.

I precise that typing the indicated command from npm fails, saying that the module has no package.json file.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for passing by.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in `node_modules` is `firestore_client.**d**.ts` (note the "d" before the ".ts")
This is for type definition only so I doubt you can instantiate `FirestoreClient` importing this file.

If you really want to import this file, try adding the file extension in the import statement.

Comment: Oh you are right... I actually had seen this but I was thinking it would work... I don't know why... Thank you for your vision.